# How can i restrict user to certain event firstly enter OPT sms code than proceed using firebase for android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

For example if user want to continue funds transfer then an OTP is send to user's number, he enter this code to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider re-authenticating the user before this sensitive operation. Assuming the user is a phone number user, you re-authenticate that user with the phone number auth flow and then get a new ID token and inspect the `auth_time` on it (on your backend or via Firebase rules) to ensure the authentication time was recent. If you get an ID token with a old `auth_time`, then you throw an error that recent login is required. This is similar to asking an email/password user to reauthenticate before updating their credit card, shipping address, etc.